# Firestore snapshot map with multiple types of object

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwXEsKRYUXU) to perform queries from Firebase firestore

As long as I had only one type of object **Note** everything is fine.
This is my object struct:

```
protocol DocumentSerializable {

init?(dictionary:[String:Any])

}

struct Note {

var title:String
var date:Date
var text:String
var type:String

var dictionary:[String:Any] {

    return [
        "title":title,
        "date":date,
        "text":text,
        "type":type,
    ]

}

}

extension Note : DocumentSerializable {

init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {

    guard let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
        let date = dictionary["date"] as? Date,
        let text = dictionary["text"] as? String,
        let type = dictionary["type"] as? String else {return nil}

    self.init(title: title, date: date, text: text, type: type)

}
```

I created another struct **Task** with same protocol and different properties, but I do not know how to map it together with the other struct, in order to have in the same array, **Note and Task**

```
var db:Firestore!
var itemsArray = [Note]() //How can I add the tasks too?

func loadData() {

    db.collection("items").order(by: "date", descending: true).getDocuments() {

        querySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {

            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {
            //HERE!
            self.itemsArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({Note(dictionary: $0.data())})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for .compactMap... it should be quite simple if you just create and instance of "Note" or "Task" depending on the document.data keys.

I am guessing that the type property in "Note" will tell you if the object is a note or a task, right? If it is you can do something like this

```
var itemsArray = [Any?]()

func loadData() {

    db.collection("items").order(by: "date", descending: true).getDocuments() {

        querySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error {

            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else {

            guard let documents = querySnapshot.documents else {return}
            for document in documents {
                let dictionary = document.data() as [String : Any]
                if dictionary["type"] == "note" {
                    let note = Note(dictionary: dictionary)
                    self.itemsArray.append(note)
                } else if dictionary["type"] == "task" {
                    let task = Task(dictionary: dictionary)
                    self.itemsArray.append(task)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If "type" doesn't tell you if the item is a note or a task the you can check the dictionary for a unique "Note" or "Task" key.